# Use Library with JNI in NetBeans WebApp

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, listlabel

I have developed a WebApp with Java-NetBeans. Now I have a library (List&Label from combit) what I want to use in it. I have all to use it in Java-Desktop-Application (JNI-Dll, Definitions). Now, I would ask, if there is a way to use it with WebApp (in a Servlet) and how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I have only to integrate the Declarations and Load the Dll with loadLibrary and all is working.